# Inheriting the width of a text element to a line break HTML

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I'm trying to inherit the width of my H3 into my line break. How would I go about doing this?

```
<div class="title">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
        <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by inherit? Are you trying to put a line break into the `<h3>`?

Comment: I'm trying to put a line break underneath the `<h3>` that will be the same width as the `<h3>`.

Comment: put </br> tag....

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do @AlfinPaul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply not use an `<hr>` tag, and instead opt for a simple underline with `text-decoration: underline`:

```css
h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could use `border-bottom`, which would allow you to increase the gap with `padding-bottom`:

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
</div>
```

Note that with the second solution, you'll want to give the `<h3>` tag `display: inline-block` so that it doesn't occupy the full line.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to set your `<div>` to have the property `display: inline-block`.

Adding the following CSS:

```
.title {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Reading @Obsidian Age's response, using a border or an underline is probably the better solution. However, my answer, answers your particular question.